Graylog with log4net Gelf Appender and AdditionalFields send NULL value
I have a web application with log4net Logger. Now I want to send log data to the Graylog Logger Service.
Sending log data from log4net to Graylog with AdditionalFields is not working in the right way.
I added the GelfUdpAppender into the application and defined this new appender in web.config with the AdditionalFields:
<appender name="GelfUdpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.GelfUdpAppender, Gelf4Net">
  <remoteAddress value="..." /> 
  <remotePort value="12201" />
  <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net">
    <param name="AdditionalFields" value="Level:%level,RequestId:%property{RequestId},Thread:%thread" />
  </layout>
</appender>

In Graylog the log entries are shown.
The values like '%level', '%thread' are converted correct
but the '%property{RequestId}' is not show the right value - just '(null)'.
Result:
"Level": "WARN",
"RequestId": "(null)", <==
"Thread": "19",

In log4net the related context property is set like:
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["RequestId"] = "123456789";
In the DebugAppender it shows the related value:
<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <layout type="CLX.Core.Web.Logging.LoggingPatternLayout, CLX.Core.Web">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{HH:mm:ss} Level:%level,RequestId:%property{RequestId},Thread:%thread %n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

Result:
15:59:57 Level:WARN,RequestId:123456789,Thread:19
According to the manual (https://github.com/jjchiw/gelf4net) the AdditionalFields property supports conversion patterns
like you would if you were using the PatternLayout class from log4net.
What is the problem about the configuration?
UPDATE
Setting the ConversionPattern inside the GelfUdpAppender with same properties:
<appender name="GelfUdpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.GelfUdpAppender, Gelf4Net">
  <remoteAddress value="..." /> 
  <remotePort value="12201" />
  <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net">
    <param name="AdditionalFields"  value="Level:%level,RequestId:%property{RequestId},Thread:%thread" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="Level:%level,RequestId:%property{RequestId},Thread:%thread %n%m" />
  </layout>
</appender>

will result the same - it's not only related to the AdditionalFields:
Level:WARN,RequestId:(null),Thread:19

I solve the problem, by not using '%property{RequestId}' in the AdditionalFields & ConversionPattern.
Per default it sends all the defined properties from the log4net.*Context.Properties list.
<appender name="GelfUdpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.GelfUdpAppender, Gelf4Net">
  <remoteAddress value="..." /> 
  <remotePort value="12201" />
  <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net">
    <param name="AdditionalFields"  value="Level:%level,Thread:%thread" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="Level:%level,Thread:%thread %n%m" />
  </layout>
</appender>

